# Java Stack/Nest Count

Tags: java, recursion

Is there a quick way in java to get the nest/recurse level?

I'm writing a function to make a list of Groups and their members.  The members can be groups as well.  It's possible that we could end up with a circular set of groups/member.

I would like to stop at some arbitrary level.

I know I could just keep a variable in a higher scope or pass an incremented parameter but am wondering if there is any stack level information immediately available in Java.

I suppose even if there is, the trick would be to know at which level of nesting you would like to start counting at.  So, the point may be moot, however I am still interested if there is any quick info on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a Throwable

It won't be fast, but you can use this: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

You'll have to traverse the stack in a meaninful way, but that should get you started

Comment: +1 I knew there was another way, forgot what it was, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thread.getStackTrace() creates a Throwable anyway. It might be clearer, but it's no more efficient.

Comment: ah, here was the original thread where I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965964/how-can-i-detect-if-a-java-class-is-called-by-its-own-main-or-from-another-clas

Comment: Ahh, perfect, I looked at that but glanced over the fact that it's an array. Thanks.

Comment: @mmyers I hadn't looked at the actual source, now I know ;) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a throwable at where you want it and and call [getStackTrace()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())

Answer (score 1):

You should adress the problem of detecting cycles directly, not via an arbitrary limit of the nesting depth. Keep a Set of nodes you have already visited and check if the current one is in there.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Throwable does have the method getStackTrace() which gives you an array of StackTraceElements